# Select subquery where last row of many-to-many relation is equals to condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: Inventory, InventoryTransaction, InventoryState.
What im trying to do is select all items from Inventory where last row of InventoryTransaction is in InventoryState euqlas 'SOLD'

> note: 1 Item can have multiple transactions, so i need to get all items that the last transaction item state is SOLD

Tables:

```
    Inventory
---------------------
id | item_name | date
1  | book      | 2016


InventoryTransaction
----------------------------------------------
id | amount | item_id | inventory_state | date
1  | 20.00  |  1      | 1               | 2016


InventoryState
-----------------
id | description
1  | 'SOLD'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Im using PostgreSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a correlated sub query to fetch the latest inventory_state from the transaction table, and then join by it to the state table:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM(
    SELECT i.*,
           (SELECT it.inventory_state FROM InventoryTransaction it
            WHERE it.item_id = i.id
            ORDER BY it.id DESC
            LIMIT 1) as last_inv_state_id
    FROM inventory i) t
JOIN InventoryState invs
 ON(t.last_inv_state_id = invs.id AND invs.description = 'SOLD')
```

Comment: This works, i just need to test and see if it gets me the right results, thanks

Comment: a good reference where can i learn to build more complex SQL like these would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just google these terms : `Postgresql correlated query` , `Postgresql multiple joins` , `Postgresql limit` .

Comment: If your looking for reference to more complex SQL using Postgresql  i would start here [SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you can replace the select with what you want if need be.

```
SELECT *

FROM    
    Inventory I
    LEFT JOIN InventoryTransaction IT 
        ON I.id = IT.id
    LEFT JOIN InventoryState InS
        ON I.id = InS.id
WHERE
    IS.description = 'SOLD'
```

Comment: When you put that IS condition in the WHERE clause, the left join suddenly executes as a regular inner join. Move to ON clause to get true left join!

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't .

Answer (score 0):

I would start with `distinct on`:

```
select i.*
from (select distinct on (item_id) it.*, ins.description
      from inventorytransaction it join
           inventorystate ins
           on it.inventory_state = ins.id
      order by item_id, date desc
     ) i
where description = 'SOLD';
```

Your data structure is rather unclear about the relationship between `inventorytransaction` and `inventory`.  I don't see an `inventory_id` of any sort, although I could speculate that it is `item_id`.